# Selection sort implementation not considering updated list

Tags: python, algorithm, selection-sort

I am trying to implement Selection sort algorithm in Python.
My first for loop is not considering updated list. How to overcome this?

```
def SelectionSort(a):
    for m_index,x in enumerate(a[:-1]):
        pos = m_index
        temp = x
        for index,y in enumerate(a[pos+1:]):
            if y < temp :
                temp = y
                to_swap = len(a) - len(a[pos+1:]) + index
            else:
                continue
        #swapping positions
        temp_var = a[to_swap]
        a[to_swap] = a[pos]
        a[pos] = temp_var
    return a

print(SelectionSort(a))
```

Comment: `a[:-1]` is a slice and so a copy/chunk of `a`, it doesn't update through the loop

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

1. The value of `x` will be taken from a copy of the original array. The swapping that might have happened in the mean time is on the original array, while `x` will just take the next value from the copy made with `a[:-1]`. One way to solve this, is to ignore `x` and just do `temp = a[pos]` instead of `temp = x`.
2. Sometimes the inner loop will never enter into the `if` block. In that case the value of `to_swap` will be undefined (if it happened on the first iteration of the the outer loop), or worse, it will be the value it had in a previous, unrelated iteration of the outer loop. One way to solve this is to initialise `to_swap = pos` before starting the inner loop.

These are the minimum number of changes needed to make it work:

```
def SelectionSort(a):
    for m_index, x in enumerate(a[:-1]):
        pos = m_index
        # 1. Make sure to grab the value from the current array, not the original 
        temp = a[pos]
        print(temp, x)
        # 2. Make sure to always initialise to_swap again!
        to_swap = pos
        for index, y in enumerate(a[pos+1:]):
            if y < temp:
                temp = y
                to_swap = len(a) - len(a[pos+1:]) + index
        temp_var = a[to_swap]
        a[to_swap] = a[pos]
        a[pos] = temp_var
    return a
```

However:

- it is inefficient to use the slice operator (`a[:-1]`, `a[pos+1:]`)
- The update of `to_swap` comes down to `to_swap = pos + 1 + index`
- Swapping can be done without temporary variable: `a[to_swap], a[pos] = a[pos], a[to_swap]`

So, this would be a better implementation:

```
def SelectionSort(a):
    for pos in range(0, len(a)-1):
        temp = a[pos]
        to_swap = pos
        for index in range(pos+1, len(a)):
            y = a[index]
            if y < temp:
                temp = y
                to_swap = index
        a[to_swap], a[pos] = a[pos], a[to_swap]
    return a
```